# May UK and US citizens visit Santiago de Chile during a layover, without payment?

Tags: us-citizens, layovers, uk-citizens, chile, santiago-de-chile

My colleague and I have a 12-hour layover in Santiago de Chile airport on our return from Argentina to the US via Chile. I am a UK citizen, my colleague is US.

Can we leave the airport and go and check out Santiago?

Do we need to pay to enter the country?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can do that and there should be no problems. Neither US nor UK citizens need a visa for Chile and the [reciprocity fee](http://onemileatatime.boardingarea.com/2014/03/04/chile-ends-160-reciprocity-fee-for-us-citizens/) that used to be charged to US citizens was abolished earlier this year.

My personal recommendation: definitely visit [Cerro Santa Lucía](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Santa_Luc%C3%ADa_Hill), a hill park in the city center from whose top you have a great view.

Comment: If you want a good top view it's better to take the uphill train to Cerro San Cristobal, but check pollution indexes before :)

Comment: @Puce: true, you see more from the top, but Cerro Santa Lucia is close to the center, and itself prettier.